# Trying to spyOn a mocked function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to perform a spyOn on a function that exists in a mocked class:

```
test.ts -

import Service from '../base_classes/Service';
jest.mock('../base_classes/Service');

const o: Component = new Component();

it('should load model specific information', async () => {
    const getSpy = jest.spyOn(Service.prototype, 'get');
    let t = await o.load(1);
    expect(t.name).toEqual('test_name');
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

__mocks__/Service.ts -

export const mockGet = jest.fn(async () => Promise.resolve({name: 
'test_name'}));
const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
return {
    get: mockGet
}
});

export default mock;
```

The resulting error is: **Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function**

I tried changing the mocked arrow function to a function(), but that didn't help.

How can I set this up so I can spy on my mocked function?

Answer (score 0):

When using `jest.mock` it automatically creates a mock for each property of the module, replacing it's functions with `jest.fn()` (without implementation). And from then on you can write assertions. There should be no reason you'd want to spy on a mock function as it's already a mock function.

You should either spy on the actual implementation or write assertions for the methods on the mocked module.

e.g.

```
it('should load model specific information', async () => {
    let t = await o.load(1);
    expect(t.name).toEqual('test_name');
    expect(Service.mock.instances[0].get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/DazzlingUnpleasantNetworks)

Comment: 'write assertions for the methods on the mocked module' - This was my first idea. But I could not sort out how to access the mocked function I created at __mocks__/Service. When I try something like 'Service.mock', I get a complaint that 'mock' is not exist on type Service. Any idea from my code why it might not be seeing it as a mocked class?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss I haven't tried Jest with TS yet, but probably you need tell the TS compiler that it's using mock which has `.mock` property

Comment: @LeeLoftiss you can try `const mockedService = Service as jest.Mock<Service>;`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Teneff. I actually tried that approach, seems like it should have worked. My guess, since nobody else has responded, that I am just doing something wrong that is preventing this approach from working.